# setPropertyActionListener doesn't set anything

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with JSF technology. I've 2 views and 2 beans. The first View (homepage.xhtml) sets a text parameter in the first Bean (UserBean) which is like so:

```
@ManagedBean   
@SessionScoped  
public class UserBean implements Serializable{

private String searchText;

public UserBean(){}

public String search() {
    return "searching?faces-redirect=true&text="+searchText;
}
```

A commandButton in the view submits the search, and calls the UserBean.search().
I have this view in the searching.xhtml, which is a simple DataList component of PrimeFaces showing a list of a user:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="text" value="#{searchView.searchText}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{searchView.init()}"></f:event>
</f:metadata>

<h:head>
    <title>Search Results</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>        
    <h:form id="resultsForm">
        <p:dataList var="user" value="#{searchView.results}" type="unordered" itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="10" styleClass="paginated">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Results for #{searchView.searchText}:
            </f:facet>

            <p:panel>
                <p:commandLink update=":resultsForm:userDetail" oncomplete="PF('userDialog').show()" title="user dettagli" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="float:right;margin-right:50px">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value = "#{user}" target="#{searchView.selectedUser}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName}, #{user.lastName}" />
                </p:commandLink>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName} (#{user.email})" style="display:inline-block" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:dataList>


    <p:dialog header="User Info" widgetVar="userDialog" modal="true" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel id="userDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty searchView.selectedUser}" columnClasses="label,value">
                    <h:outputText value="First name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{searchView.selectedUser.firstName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{searchView.selectedUser.lastName}" />  

                    <h:outputText value="Calendar" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{searchView.selectedUser.visibility}" />

                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    <br/>
</h:body>
```

In the end, I've this backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchView implements Serializable {

private List<User> results;
private User selectedUser;
private String searchText;
@EJB
private SearchingManager sm;

public void init() {
    System.out.println("print search text:" + searchText);
    results = sm.search(searchText);
}

public SearchView() {
}

public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {
    System.out.println("setter of selected user");
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
}

public User getSelectedUser() {
    System.out.println("getter of selected user");
    return selectedUser;
}
```

It works and shows the results of the search correctly but when it opens the page of results I notice this output:
**Informazioni:   print search text: Mario

Informazioni:   getter of selected user**
So I'm wondering why that *getSelectedUser()* is called without selecting any user. Moreover when I select a user it shows an empty dialog and this is the outcome:
**Informazioni:   getter of selected user

Informazioni:   getter of selected user

Informazioni:   getter of selected user

Informazioni:   print search text: Mario

Informazioni:   getter of selected user**
So it recalls the *init()* function why?
And the worst thing is that if we close the Dialog and reopen it, the result is something like that but with
**Informazioni:   print search text: null**
and it stops because of NullPointerException.
I'm spending days searching about this setPropertyActionListener but I can't understand this behavior of the system.

Comment: Set the process attribute of `<p:commandLink>` to `@this` like `<p:commandLink process="@this"...>` which defaults to `@form`. If you are on JSF 2.2 then, change `<f:event>` to `<f:viewAction>` and remove those parenthesis after the `init()` method which are dangling unnecessarily there such as `<f:viewAction action="#{searchView.init}"/>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, i removed the `<f:viewEvent>`replacing it with the `<f:viewAction>`and I have no more the calling to init() every time and the problem of NullPointerException. But still the dialog is empty and i see a **Informazioni: getter of selected user** when the page is opened also with that attribute in the commandLink

Comment: Do you actually mean that the setter method `public void setSelectedUser(User selectedUser) {...}` is never invoked? (Of course, getters are, by nature [called multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1391249). Just do not put critical business logic in getter methods and do not worry about them).

Comment: Yes the fact is that the getSelectedUser was invoked at the opening of the page, without I select any user, and the setter never invoked. Now we tried making the baking bean `@SessionScoped` instead of `@ViewScoped` and calling the target `selectedUser` instead of `searchView.selectedUser` and all seems to work correctly, but still i don't understand why.

Comment: I have not yet mentioned anything about it - just kept it aside but why is this stray `</h:link>` there below the `<p:commandLink>` following the `<h:outputText>`? It should give you a parse error.

Comment: Yep sorry it was my error copying the code, in the program I canceled it, now I edited it also in the question.